# Age OLd bitcoin core wallet ".dat or .bak or nothing or Dumpwallet .txt or dumping pywallet "recorder type wallet ??

Tags: bitcoin-core, backup, bitcoin-qt-setup

I have one wallet.dat "or lot of wallet", but he's valids !

why, when I loadwallet or import my dumpwallet file,

My bitcoins...

With old age, on old wallet bitcoin-qt (bitcoin core) version , but normally here,

I see nothing, not see Transactions not see bitcoin ? (0)

It is the question !

Comment: Are you sure that your wallet.dat contains Bitcoin? It may contain other types (alternative) of coins. You can check if there are other types of coins in it by using pywallet. `python pywallet.py --dumpwallet --wallet=/foo/bar/wallet.dat`

Comment: And another possible problem with "old wallet Bitcoin QT" is that it may not show all address transaction history, especially mined transactions. So, you should try to run your wallet.dat on a [matches version](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases?page=1) to find out if there are any missing transactions/addresses or not.

Comment: python pywallet.py --dumpwallet --wallet=/foo/bar/wallet.dat – command is simple dumpwallet ? And I ve test the version anterior but I ve not possibility to open wallets !

Comment: Is your Bitcoin Core fully synced with the blockchain? If not, it may show a 0 BTC balance, so wait for it to catch up with the network.

Comment: no, why my bitcoins not here, ? blockchain here, wallet.dat here, bitcoins not here ... ! reading debug.log tell my If one bug ? possible ? think ?

Comment: what what should be the type file, of wallet bitcoin backup ? .dat, .txt or nothing point ?

Comment: should I, for the rescanblockchain, script 0 8XX XXX the height of block exact ?! Question of mempool ? possible.

Comment: 1. wallet.dat is the bitcoin QT  backup file
2. Yes, Now the height of block is around 802,8xx at the time you post.        I don't know if I understand what you want to say correctly, However This seems like a long Q&A. So if you have another question please look at my profile page, there is a contact channel.